# plotting achartengine loop

Tags: android, sqlite, loops, graph, achartengine

I have implemented achartengine into my project and I have it displaying info from sqlite database.    Everything is working great now except everytime I delete a row from database it cuts off at that row and only graphs the previous rows.    I need it to skip the deleted rows and continue reading all rows until the last one.   I have been working on this forever now and I don't know what to do from here.   Thank you for any help and pointers!

Chris

In my database activity:

```
public String getValue1(long l) {
    String[] columns = new String[]{ EMP_DEPT };
    Cursor c = db.query(EMP_TABLE, columns, EMP_ID + "=" + l, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null){
    c.moveToFirst();
    String value1 = c.getString(0);
    return value1;
    }
    return null;
    }






public String getValue2(long l) {
    String[] columns = new String[]{ EMP_DATE1 };
    Cursor c = db.query(EMP_TABLE, columns, EMP_ID + "=" + l, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null){
    c.moveToFirst();
    String value2 = c.getString(0);
    return value2;
    }
    return null;
    }
```

In my graph activity:

```
        TimeSeries myseries = new TimeSeries("Test");

    try{

        for (int i = 1; !c.isAfterLast(); i++)  {

         String value1 = db.getValue1(i);
         String value2 = db.getValue2(i);

         c.moveToNext();

         double x7 = Double.parseDouble(value1);
         double y7 = Double.parseDouble(value2);

         myseries.add(x7, y7);  

         }

    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println("nothing");}
```

Comment: What is the issue you have with AChartEngine?

Comment: I am using AChartEngine to draw a graph of my sqlite data, but if I delete a row in my database AChartEngine will only dispaly previous rows from deleted row in database. I am basicly looking for a way to continue through and skip over deleted rows when plotting the chart.          To answer your specific question I'm not having any problems with AChartEngine.....   I'm having problems plotting it.      I'm pretty new to a lot of this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a chart without using any Built in jar files like `achartengine`.

Check this [`Bar Chart in Android With out any Built in jars`](http://rakhi577.wordpress.com/2012/10/11/bar-chart-in-android-with-out-any-built-in-jars/)

Comment: Thank you for the idea, however I need to use a bar charts as well as pie charts and line charts.